# How to set different CSS property to same element define in one component in angular

Tags: css, angular, components, dynamic-programming

I have a component which contain element with class hello, this component is render in almost 2 more components but each component has it's own requirement of height. How can I do this in angular. Components have no relation

I tried the encapsulation and global styling then updating locally but nothing work

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) using the `<>` icon.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 0):

You can Handle it by using @Input() and conditions

Answer (score 0):

To address varying height requirements for the same class in Angular components with no relation, consider using `ViewEncapsulation.None` and applying specific styles directly in each component's styleUrls.

This allows independent styling without encapsulation.

```js
@Component({
  standalone: true,
  selector: 'app-no-encapsulation',
  template: ``,
  styles: [''],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send an input parameter to the component with the height size,like small(sm) or medium(md) and then in css define two different class styles like `.sm{height: 25px;} .md{height: 60px;}`, finally using an NgClass you can define which class will be applied so you'll have the desired height. PD. I recommend you to use a CSS methodology like BEM so the height would be a modifier and it'd be more cleaner solution.

Comment: Please explain more and my components are independent

Comment: can you send us the code of your components? what do you mean with independent?